# Proof that the counting measure of rationals is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was trying to solve this problem and want to check if my reasoning is correct.

*Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\mu(A):=\#\{q, q \in \mathbb{Q}\cap A\}$, prove that $\mu$ is a measure.*

The only challenging condition to check is countable additivity, namely that $\mu(\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathbb(N)} = \sum_{i\in\mathbb(N)}\mu(A_i)$ for $\{A_i\}$ disjoints.

First, if $\exists i:\mu\left(A_i\right) = \infty$ then equality trivially holds, with both sides being unbounded. So let's assume that there is no such a $i$. 
Assuming that I managed to prove that $\mu\left(.\right)$ is finitely additive and monotone, I want to use the proposition that

> for finitely additive measure and for $\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathbb(N)}$
>   descending with $\cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i=\emptyset$ , if $\lim_i
> > \mu\left(A_i\right)=0$ then $\mu\left(.\right)$ is a measure

First we have that $\mu\left(A_i\right)\geq \mu\left(A_{i+1}\right)$ so that $\mu\left(A_i\right)$ is monotonically decreasing (non strictly) and it is lower bounded (by 0) so that there is a g.l.b. $\geq 0$.

Argue that the g.l.b is $>0$, it means that $\forall i,A_i \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset$. This implies that there is at least one rational $q$ that is in all $A_i$, so that $q\in \cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i$. However this contradicts that $\cap_{i\in \mathbb{N}}A_i=\emptyset$. So the g.l.b can not be $>0$, which implies that it is equal to 0.

Is there something shady in that proof ?
Thanks.

Comment: Presumably you want $\mathbb{Q}\cap A$ in the definition of $\mu$.

Comment: There was a typo , it is an intersection, redacted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so clear to me why you can conclude that there is some rational number $q$ which is contained in every $A_i$. I think this needs more explanation.

Allow me to suggest an alternate approach to the problem:

1. First show that if $\{\mu_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of Borel measures and
   $$ \mu(A)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu_n(A) $$
   then $\mu$ is also a Borel measure. This should be a straightforward consequence of Tonelli's theorem.
2. Show that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there is a corresponding Borel measure $\delta_x$ defined by $\delta_x(A)=1$ if $x\in A$, and $\delta_x(A)=0$ otherwise.
3. Show that the measure $\mu$ you are considering can be written as
   $$ \mu=\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Q}}\delta_q $$
   Note that this sum is countable because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.